Elasticsearch Query for Exact Substring Matching with Spaces
I'm trying to perform an exact substring match in Elasticsearch, including substrings that contain spaces. Here’s what I need:

Search for an exact substring within a larger text field.
The substring may contain spaces.
The substring may be a partial word and not necessarily a full word.
I want to match the substring exactly as it appears, not just individual terms.

I've tried the following approaches without success:
Wildcard Query:
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "description": {
        "value": "*substring with spaces*",
        "case_insensitive": true
      }
    }
  }
}

Query String with Analyze Wildcard:
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*substring with spaces*",
      "fields": ["description"],
      "analyze_wildcard": true,
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  }
}

Neither approach returns the expected results when the substring contains spaces.
Example:
Field: description
Value: "quick brown fox"
Substring can be any of the followings - "quick brown fox", "quick bro", "quick" or "brown f" etc and I still want it to match exactly.
How can I construct an Elasticsearch query to achieve exact substring matching, including spaces and partial words?

If partial words always begin at the beginning of the word you can use match_phrase_prefix:
DELETE test
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "description": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_bulk?refresh=true
{ "index": { "_id": "1" } }
{ "description": "The quick brown fox"}
{ "index": { "_id": "2" } }
{ "description": "The slow red fox with brown spots wasn't that quick"}

POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "description": "quick brown fox"
    }
  }
}

POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "description": "quick bro"
    }
  }
}

POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "description": "quick"
    }
  }
}

POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "description": "brown f"
    }
  }
}


If you want to match any queries that can potentially start in the middle of the word and don't mind pretty bad performance degradation you can do this:
DELETE test
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "description": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_bulk?refresh=true
{ "index": { "_id": "1" } }
{ "description": "The quick brown fox"}
{ "index": { "_id": "2" } }
{ "description": " jumps over the lazy dog"}


POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "description": {
        "value": "*ick bro*",
        "case_insensitive": true
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "description": {
        "value": "*wn fox*",
        "case_insensitive": true
      }
    }
  }
}


In case you have millions of different descriptions, descriptions are exceeding the keyword limits of 32K or this is the primarily way of searching this field you can switch from keyword type to wildcard type. This will relax the keyword limitations but will come with increased storage and indexing costs.

None of the approaches work here. Also, the substring may not always be the prefix. For ex it can be just like 'ick bro', 'wn fox' etc.

The second approach works with "ick bro" and "wn fox", you just need to reindex as I have demonstrated in my example.

Ok got it, you used thye keyword type to query. I see there is some performance issue as you mentioned. Would you advice to use wildcard type for this field??
Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html#wildcard-field-type

It depends on your data. If you can work within keyword limitations, then using keywords is fine. However, wildcards are more versatile but come with additional storage and indexing costs. In my experience, when users need to search for substrings, it’s often a sign of a poorly designed search experience. I recommend identifying and addressing the underlying issues that compel users to resort to such methods instead of relying on substrings.

We have a simple use case where there is a search bar and user can input any string(or substring) and we need to display all the results matching to that string(or substring). It's not like auto-complete or suggestion like features, we want exact matching.

That sounds like a strange legacy use-case that was inherited from an old system that didn't know how to do better. Let me know if I can help you more with your original question. Don't forget to accept answers if they actually answer your question, that will increase your chances of getting answers in the future.
